# How can I apply a continuous gradient across the front and back covers in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, gradient, page-layout

I get how to create a gradient across multiple objects, but this doesn't seem to work across pages.

I've also tried creating a master spread and applying the gradient across two background objects. However, when I apply the master to the covers the gradient readjusts to just the one background frame.

Would appreciate any tips or assistance!

Comment: Hi Jerald! Thanks for your question and welcome to GD.SE. If you have any questions about this site, or about Stack Exchange in general, have a look at the [help]. If that doesn't help enough, feel free to pop into the local [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) and ask away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine your cover to be spread out, with the spine face up.

1. On your front page 'spread', draw one big shape that extends to the left of the front cover far enough to cover the imaginary back cover as well, including bleed. Fill this shape with your desired gradient.
2. Copy this object.
3. On your back cover 'spread', choose <kbd>Edit > Paste in Place</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think to try one big shape. It actually works without needing two extended shapes on each cover as well - Once I create the big shape on the master spread, applying it to the front and back covers automatically clips the respective areas of the image!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set up your InDesign document so the back and front page are shown as a spread instead of being two separate pages.

When creating the document, set it up with the wanted *Number of Pages*, enable *Facing Pages* and set *Start Page #* to *2*.

[image]

Now your document only consists of whole spreads:

[image]

But the page numbers are wrong which will give you problems if you use automatic page numbering etc.

Right-click the first page (which is supposed to be the last page), enter *Numbering & Section Options* and set *Start Page Numbering at* to the last page number. Then right-click the second page (which is supposed to be the first page), enter *Numbering & Section Options* and set *Start Page Numbering at* to *1*.

Now your document should have the proper page numbering:

[image]

Beware that if you export a single page PDF with *All* pages, it will start with the last page. To get the the front page as the first page you need to specify that you want to export pages *1-[second last page number], [last page number]*. (If you have 8 pages it would be *1-7,8*.)

If you export a PDF in spreads there is no way you can get the front and back to show as single pages.